# Añadir un elemento html con append y obtener ese elemento sin tener que buscarlo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por ejemplo si añado un select con .append() y luego quiero añadir options a ese select añadido, ¿Cómo lo puedo asignar a una variable a la vez que lo añado?

La única forma que he conseguido es buscarla después de añadirla con el método .find()

```
$(this).append('<select></select>');
var select = $(this).find('select');
select.append($('<option>', {
    value: 5,
    text: 'texto',
))
```

Esto creo que no es correcto o algo no he echo bien

```
var select = $(this).append('<select></select>');
select.append($('<option>', {
    value: 5,
    text: 'texto',
))
```

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de hacerlo más elegante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas hacer, tener en una variable el elemento que estás añadiendo sería justo lo contrario de lo que estás haciendo.

```
var this_ = $(this).append(elemento);
```

La variable `this_` hace referencia al elemento jQuery `$(this)`

```
var select = $('<select></select>').appendTo($(this));
```

En este caso la variable `select` hace referencia **al elemento jQuery creado**. (Ya que estos métodos de jQuery devuelven el propio objeto).

```js
var body = $('body');
var select = $('<select></select>').appendTo(body);
var optiona = $('<option value="aaa">aaa</option>').appendTo(select);
var optionb = $('<option value="bbb">bbb</option>').appendTo(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo le asignaría un id:

```
$(this).append('<select id="appended"></select>');

$("#appended").append($('<option>', {
    value: 5,
    text: 'texto',
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema con tu código es poner `<select></select>`, sólo deberías poner `<select>`, y quedaría así:

```
    $(this).append('<select>').append($('<option>', { 
        value: 5,
        text : 'texto'
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma y es una forma muy entendible seria la siguiente:

```js
//fase de creacion de elementos
var body = $('body');//variable para el body
var select = $('<select></select>');//crear el select
var optionA = $('<option value="A">opcion A</option>');//creas los options
var optionB = $('<option value="B">opcion B</option>');
//fase de enlazar elementos.
select.append(optionA);
select.append(optionB);
body.append(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```